# Web query - objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I used simliar code for another app of mine, it has been working fine but when I tried it (a different IP/cgi script) for my current app, it is not working.

```
NSString *iQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"206.196.111.206/rego/test.cgi?country=AU"];  
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iQuery] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorStr];    
NSData *resultJson = [query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
if(query){
   NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {        
   printf("Error is: %s", errorStr);
}
```

If I paste the query: 
206.196.111.206/rego/test.cgi?country=AU 
into IE or firefox, it does what it should (returns 4 digits code)

I have also tried with escaped string:

```
    NSString *iQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"206.196.111.206/rego/test.cgi?country=AU"]; 
    NSString *escapedURL = [iQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorStr];
    NSData *resultJson = [query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
    if(query) {
        NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    } else {
        printf("Error is: %s", errorStr);    
    }
```

if(query) returns false.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does "`errorStr`" (which should be a "`NSError`" object, from which you can get the "`localizedDescription`" string from) give any useful hints?

Comment: Yes, the way to print errorStr was wrong, thanks Michael for correcting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the protocol prefix `"http://"` before your request string, this solves the problem, as i am getting four digits back, otherwise the contents of error is:

`"Error the operation could not be completed."`